# Parse nested maps in a function (gatling)

Tags: scala

I have a map like this:

```
{
    "user": 
    {
        "name": "Jon Doe",
        "age": "6",
        "birthdate": {
            "timestamp": 1456424096
        },
        "gender": "M"    
    }
}
```

and a function like this

```
def setUser(user: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any]={
    var usr = Map("name"-> user.get("name").getOrElse(""),
             "gender" -> user.get("gender").getOrElse(""),
             "age" -> user.get("age").getOrElse(""),
             "birthday" -> patient.get("birthdate")) 

      return usr
}
```

And I want to have the value of "timestamp" (1456424096) mapped in the "birthday" field.

For now I have this : **Some%28%7Btimestamp%3D1456424096%7D%29**

I'm very new to this. Can someone help me get the value of "timestamp"?

Comment: is this issue impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want just to get rid of nested birthday (not nested user) it can look like that:

```
val oldData: Map[String, Any] = Map(
  "user" -> Map(
    "name" -> "John Doe",
    "age" -> 6,
    "birthday" -> Map("timestamp" -> 1234454666),
    "gender" -> "M"
  )
)

def flattenBirthday(userMap: Map[String, Any]) = Map(
  "user" -> (userMap("user").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]] + (
    "birthday" -> userMap("user").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("birthday").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("timestamp")
  ))
)

val newData = flattenBirthday(oldData)
```

But in general dealing with nested immutable maps will be ugly. If you extract that data from JSONs (like in your example) it is better to use some library to deserialize that data into case class objects.